# Incorrect Date Value в mysql. Что делать?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

На сервере в БД есть колонка с типом данных DATE. У данного типа формат строковых литералов по умолчанию: ГГГГ-ММ-ДД.
Существует код в программе для получения данных с БД:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($@"SELECT * FROM `{nameTable}`", db.getConnection());
```

Для моего dataGridView указан формат колонки с датой:

```
dgv.Columns["дата добавления"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

На форме находится поле dateTimePicker, которое корректно получает и отображает данные yyyy-MM-dd:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value = (DateTime)dgv[i, rowIndex].Value;
```

Для dateTimePicker установлен CustomFormat yyyy-MM-dd:

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

При обновлении данных на сервере - обновляется и дата следующим образом:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
                    $@"UPDATE `физические лица - клиенты`
                    SET `дата добавления` = '{dateTimePicker1.Value}'
                    WHERE `Код клиента` = '{textBoxArray()[0].Text}'",db.getConnection());
```

Но при добавлении возникает ошибка:

> Incorrect date value: '05.02.2020 0:00:00' for column 'дата
> добавления' at row 1

Не могу понять откуда нули, и кажется, что именно из-за них ругается. Как убрать данные нули? Или что делать? Куда копать?

Comment: *и кажется, что именно из-за них ругается* Нет, ругается на формат `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(
                    $@"UPDATE `физические лица - клиенты`
                    SET `дата добавления` = '{dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")}'
                    WHERE `Код клиента` = '{textBoxArray()[0].Text}'",db.getConnection());
```

но лучше использовать SqlCommand c параметрами:

```
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();
string SQL = "UPDATE `физические лица - клиенты`
                        SET `дата добавления` = @date
                        WHERE `Код клиента` = '@client'";
command.CommandText = SQL;
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dateTimePicker1.Value);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client", textBoxArray()[0].Text);
command.Connection = db.getConnection();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```